# How to configure multiple network in Ubuntu physical machine?

Tags: 14.04, networking

We are having two physical network card for redundancy in network. I tried to connect after installing ubuntu but it just showing connecting dialogue box not connecting.

Comment: Do you have a DHCP server on your network?

Comment: Yes we have but we don't have access to that one